# Something is writing to my logs and I can't stop it

Tags: azure, logging, serilog, azure-webapps

I've a web app running in Azure. It uses Serilog for logging.

Using the `Serilog:MinimimLevel:Override` AppConfig entries I'm able to control the level of output I want.

Except

Something is writing with the `SourceContext` of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics" and it's writing 2 messages for each Http call to the `/api/health`, one marking the start of the call, the other the end.

The other "interesting" thing is that the message content is not in the same format as all of the other messages that go to the log. I have a custom Json Formatter that I use but these magic log entries do not appear to be using it.

I can't find anything in my `Program.cs` that might be responsible. I did have

```
  app.UseElasticApm(builder.Configuration, new HttpDiagnosticsSubscriber());
```

which was the only thing that looked suspicious, but taking that out has had no impact.

Whatever it is that is calling it is doing so about 6 times/minute.

Can anyone suggest anything that may tell me how to stop this output from appearing?

Comment: check this [link](https://andrewlock.net/using-serilog-aspnetcore-in-asp-net-core-3-excluding-health-check-endpoints-from-serilog-request-logging/) , if it helps

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the AspNetCore logs.  You might be able to disable it like [this](https://dev.to/kasuken/enabling-and-disabling-logs-in-aspnet-core-6-4076)